# Connection among webparts getting lost when editting aspx

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, web-part, performancepoint, connected-web-parts

I have a little problem. Im creating a custom aspx page to serve as an advanced dashboard for PPS webparts (mainly filters and reports) in SP2010. I didnt mention this in the title since I think that the problem is general.

**Dashboard designer way**

I need to insert elements (mainly html) between the webparts, which makes it hard to do the dashboard in a designer, because everytime I do the deploy, the aspx of the dashboard gets overwritten.

**Custom aspx page**

This works quite fine, but so far I have discovere a big disadvantage. I create a page from scratch in sharepoint designer, define WebPartZones and elements that I need, even insert some additional css and javascript. Via IE I add the webparts (filters and reports) to the page and then I edit their connections so they interact among each other. So far so good. However, when I decide that the aspx needs a change and I edit it in the sharepoint designer and save it, all the connections among the webparts disapear.

How can I prevent the connections to disapear? Where does sharepoint store these conenctions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a known issue with SharePoint Designer.  If you read [Maintain, edit, and update PerformancePoint dashboards](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh344829%28v=office.14%29.aspx) you'll see the following warning:

> Do not click Edit in SharePoint Designer. You cannot use Microsoft SharePoint Designer to edit dashboard pages that contain PerformancePoint Web Parts. Otherwise, data connections to those Web Parts might fail and data will no longer display.

You can use the "thin" / web edit mode in SharePoint to modify the Dashboard.

Comment: Interesting and sad. I have even created the whole dashboard by myself, not using the dashboard designer. That was actually intentional since I needed to add multiple webpart zones and additional javascript. Is this a bug or are there any implementational complications which restrict MS to fix it?

Comment: @Santhos if you want to drop to an API, you can use Fiddler, and see what API Dashboard Designer uses.  Don't know about a bug, but I'm not a fan of SharePoint Designer (cough Frontpage) so I'm hoping they don't invest much time into it.  It has never worked for me.

Comment: Thanks Josh. I might try it. There must be a way to do the connections programatically. Maybe I could write everything through SPD and the SP web administration and then run a small c# script which would initialize all the connections. With such a script I could easily modify the aspx anytime I wanted and then just re-run the script.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its related but in the past i have had issues with the checkin/out process that exists both in SP UI and SPD.

If you edit a page in SPD and DON'T check it in then you goto the same page in SP UI and "edit" the page to manage your web parts etc then you will in effect be out of sync and work will be lost.

I would manage the html part via content web parts which reference the txt files which contain all the html and are stored in a document library.

Or do all you work in the custom.aspx in SPD and ensure you manage the checkin/out process vigilantly.

HTH

S

Comment: I was trying to solve a slightly different problem, so your answer is not really related. However, thank you for your time anyway.